# Highhest Number's key in a GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple class:

```
class Balls
{
    public int BallType;  
}
```

And i have a really simple list:

```
var balls = new List<Balls>() 
{ 
    new Balls() { BallType = 1},
    new Balls() { BallType = 1},
    new Balls() { BallType = 1},
    new Balls() { BallType = 2}
};
```

I've used `GroupBy` on this list and I want to get back the key which has the highest count/amount:
After I used `x.GroupBy(q => q.BallType)` I tried to use `.Max()`, but it returns 3 and I need the key which is 1.

I also tried to use `Console.WriteLine(x.GroupBy(q => q.Balltype).Max().Key);` but it throws `System.ArgumentException`.

Comment: In most cases just getting the max leave out the value.  So you want to do a select to get both value and count.  Instead of using Max I like to use OrderByDescending and then take First : var results = balls.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { value = x.Key, count = x.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.count).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
var mostCommonBallType = balls
    .GroupBy(k => k.BallType)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
    .Last().Key
```

You group by the BallType, order by the count of items in the group, get the last value (since order by is in an ascending order, the most common value would be the last) and then return it's key

Answer (score 1):

Some came up with the idea to order the sequence:

```
var mostCommonBallType = balls
.GroupBy(k => k.BallType)
.OrderBy(g => g.Count())
.Last().Key
```

Apart from that it is more efficient to `OrderByDescending` and then take the `FirstOrDefault`, you also get in trouble if your collection of Balls is empty.

If you use a different overload of GroupBy, you won't have these problems

```
var mostCommonBallType = balls.GroupBy(
    // KeySelector:
    k => k.BallType,

    // ResultSelector:
    (ballType, ballsWithThisBallType) => new
    {
        BallType = ballType,
        Count = ballsWithThisBallType.Count(),
    })
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count)
    .Select(group => group.BallType)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This solves the previously mentioned problems. However, if you only need the 1st element, why would you order the 2nd and the 3rd element? Using Aggregate instead of OrderByDescending will enumerate only once:

Assuming your collection is not empty:

```
var result = ... GroupBy(...)
    .Aggregate( (groupWithHighestBallCount, nextGroup) =>
         (groupWithHighestBallCount.Count >= nextGroup.Count) ?
             groupWithHighestBallCount : nextGroup)
    .Select(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

Aggregate takes the first element of your non-empty sequence, and assigns it to groupWithHighestBallCount. Then it iterates over the rest of the sequence, and compare this nextGroup.Count with the groupWithHighestBallCount.Count. It keeps the one with the hightes value as the next groupWithHighestBallCount. The return value is the final groupWithHighestBallCount.

See that Aggregate only enumerates once?